# Eclipse XML Layout Attribute starting with Android1 instead of Android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, xml-layout

I was working on my project and i tried to change my layout. I wanted to add radiogroup so i pressed ctrl + space for suggestions and now every attribute starts from **Android1** instead of **Android**. 
Why its occuring ? Is there any specific reason or i just have to live with it :(

This is the screenshot for better understanding - [image] 
**Note** : Don't suggest clean project & restart eclipse. I have already done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `xmlns:android1="..."` in RelativeLayout, remove it.

Comment: I didn't looked there at all. Don't know how it got changed. Thanks it reverted back to normal